# String.Concat() add unexpected 'carriage return' chars

Tags: c#, .net, string, concatenation

Is there any reason why after joining 4 separate strings with no `'carriage return'` chars inside, what I get is a single string with `'carriage return'` chars inserted in random places?

These chars are placed between words.. It's so strange.
Here's an example:

```
Before: user_tb.surname    
After: user_tb.surn[CR][LF]ame
```

Where **`[CR][LF]`** is the 'carriage return' char

Here's the instruction:

```
String.Concat(finalSelectStatement, fromStatement, finalJoinStatement, finalOrderByStatement);
```

All the strings inside the Concat are ok before the concatenation

Comment: Please, check you code: it may occur that it's `String.AppendLine()` (which adds new line) somewhere in the code

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Sorry, I typed String.Append() instead of String.Concat().. I've already updated the answer

Comment: How are you determining that there's a line break in there? Are you sure that it's not just wrapping the text visually and the `String` object is not actually affected?

Comment: `String.Concat` does not add anything other than what you tell it. Your input strings alread contain the linefeed characters, String.Concat just tucks them together. Check the code that generates/retrieves the contents of those variables, that's where the problem is.

Comment: It doesn't. You misdiagnosed your issue, but you're not showing us enough code for us to spot where the actual issue is.

Comment: "Where [CR][LF] is the 'carriage return' char". [CR] would be the carriage return and [LF] would be a line feed. Those two characters together constitute a Windows line break, where Unix-based OSes use just a line feed.

Comment: Nope, passing this string inside sql cause an error, so I copied this string inside an editor and saw this chars.. I tried with 2/3 different editors.. same result

Comment: You can read [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,3197) yourself and confirm that there's no magical "insert extra characters" code.

Comment: for example, before the Concat, the finalSelectStatement is ok, with no 'carriage return + line feed' chars. After the concat I found some of this chars between the words contained in the finalSelectStatementString..

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know, this is so strange.. :/ I'm pretty sure that before the Concat those chars are not in the string..

Comment: You've shown us *one line* of code, and we can assure you that it isn't doing what you claim it's doing. As Lasse said, you need to create a MCVE or there's no way we can help you.

Comment: If this only happens in your production code you must at least show us screenshots of your variables so that we too can see that there is no such characters in the input strings.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I wish I can share more code with you guys but I'm not sure I can.. I have to ask because it may contains some information that our customer doesn't want to share

Comment: I bet if you replaced your input strings with some hard coded strings you wouldn't see new lines being inserted, proving they're contained in your inputs.

Comment: Have you followed the MCVE link? We don't necessarily need your *real code*. We need you to create an *example* piece of code that demonstrates the same problem. There shouldn't be an issue with sharing such an example (of course, often, by trying to create a MCVE, you'll discover the underlying issue yourself).

Comment: I got it, it's because of the Visual Studio's Immediate Window that I was using in order to retrieve the concatenated string to check. Switching to the 'Text Visualizer' window solved the issue..
I still have some problems with the result though.. a word inside the first string change from 'vstoExportShippingPlanningSerials_vw' to 'vstoExportShippingP...ls_vw' it's like truncated..

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The problem with the MCVE is that I get this problem only whit these input values.. I've never had this type of problem with .Concat() before and the code in this project works with other values

Comment: Again.. this was a problem with the 'Text Visualizer' window.. I think that the result was too long so he truncated 'vstoExportShippingPlanningSerials_vw' to 'vstoExportShippingP...ls_vw'
In order to be sure to read the right value, I wrote the Concat() result on a file and it was ok! Thank to everyone and sorry to bother you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was related to the Visual Studio's 'Immediate Windows' function.. I switched to the 'Text Visualizer' function by adding a Watch on the instruction and I solved it..

Unfortunately I found another issue in 'Text Visualizer'.. One of the word inside the result changed from 'vstoExportShippingPlanningSerials_vw' to 'vstoExportShippingP...ls_vw'..
And in this case, I think that Visual Studio trim the result if it's too long..

So I decided to write the result on disk and what I found is that the result was right!